# mmap() again, re-using former mmap() result fails - invalidates original ptr?

Tags: c, mmap

when I make a call to `mmap`:

```
  ptr = mmap(NULL, ...);
```

and ask the system to provide a buffer and map the file into it, then call `mmap` again with

```
  ptr2 = mmap(ptr, ...);
```

trying to re-use the original buffer.

If this second call fails (for whatever reason), does this invalidate my `ptr` from the first `mmap(NULL, ...)` invocation?

Or can I still use that memory?

Comment: first argument is used as hint only, if your 2d mapping failed result of the first one should be untouched

Answer (score 1):

mmap doesn't map a file into a buffer, it replaces the address space in your process with pages that are fulfilled from and retired into a file on disk.  mmap's use of address space doesn't remember the previous use, so a second overlapping mmap usually destroys the mappings provided by the first.  You can of course restore them afterward by mapping the original space.  (If the overlap was at end, with an offset into the same address space).

Comment: Thanks for the information. But what happens if overlapping - in extreme identical - regions being used for subsequent mmap()'s? Does still any mmap() have to have it's munmap()? Or does one subsume the other? E.g. a 1st mmap() uses a big chunk. Then a 2nd mmap() tries to map somewhere within (a part of the original one - bytes left before and after from the 1st mmap()). Does this require to munmap() in the reverse order? Does the 2nd mmap() update the file content of the 1st mmap()? Where can i find more detailed information? The manual page is not that exhaustive.

Comment: It certainly isn't the case that munmap in the reverse order is the right thing to do.  I just tested it out on linux and munmap on the original region does succeed though with the effect of destroying the remaining tail of the full region, which is what I would expect.  The reason the man page doesn't address this use case is likely because most people don't use mmap in the way you intend to.  The way mmap works on most OSes is that it dumbly overwrites the mappings for successive page addresses your mapping and munmap deletes the one and only mapping of each page on the range you specify.